# How to stream a Map of Map

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two Maps received as parameter in the function below...

```
private static BigDecimal getValueBudgetUnrealized (Map<SKUIdCanalIdDTO, Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal>> factByMonth, Map<SKUIdCanalId, Map<LocalDate, Budget>> budgetByMonth) {

    }
```

What I need to do, is to check if the keys of the Map inside (LocalDate) doesn't contain in the other Map, just like I did in the other example below:

```
private static BigDecimal getValueBudgetUnrealized (Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> factByMonth, Map<LocalDate, BudgetDTO> budgetByMonth, Measure measure) {
        return budgetByMonth.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(budget-> !factByMonth.containsKey(budget.getKey()))
                .map(budget-> budget.getValue().getValueByMeasure(measure))
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    }
```

Well, I've been stuck with this, and I couldn't manage to solve this problem.

Comment: It would better if you share `BudgetDTO`. And you **need to clarify** (in pseudocode or at least in plain English) how do want these nested Maps to be compared?

Comment: Use *edit* button, or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73935209/edit) to update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to find the dates in the one map which are not in the other. You'll also need to do it the other way if you want to find all the discrepancies through this method.

```
List<LocalDate> datesInFactByMonthNotInBudgetByMonth = factByMonth.values().stream()
        .map(Map::keySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .filter(localDateFromFactByMonth -> budgetByMonth.values().stream()
                .map(Map::keySet)
                .flatMap(Set::stream)
                .noneMatch(localDateFromFactByMonth::equals))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want **all** *entries* from each *nested map* from `budgetByMonth` which doesn't have a matching in any of the maps contained within `factByMonth` to contribute the resulting `BigDecimal` value, firstly you can generate a `Set` of *key* which can be encountered in `factByMonth` and then check every entry from `budgetByMonth` against this set.

In order to flatten the data from the nested maps, you can use [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) operation, which expects a *function* that generates a new stream from every element of the pipeline.

That's how it might look like:

```
private static BigDecimal getTotalOrcamentoARealizarBySKUCanal(
    Map<SKUIdCanalIdDTO, Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal>> factByMonth,
    Map<SKUIdCanalId, Map<LocalDate, Budget>> budgetByMonth
) {
    Set<LocalDate> factByMonthKeys = factByMonth.values().stream()
        .flatMap(map -> map.keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    return budgetByMonth.values().stream()
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .filter(entry -> !factByMonthKeys.contains(entry.getKey()))
        .map(entry -> entry.getValue().`~ get BigDecimal from Budget object somehow ~`)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

And in case if you want to reject the **hole map** from `budgetByMonth` if any of its *keys* is present within `factByMonth`, then you need to apply `filter()` before flattening the data.

```
private static BigDecimal getTotalOrcamentoARealizarBySKUCanal(
    Map<SKUIdCanalIdDTO, Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal>> factByMonth,
    Map<SKUIdCanalId, Map<LocalDate, Budget>> budgetByMonth
) {
    Set<LocalDate> factByMonthKeys = factByMonth.values().stream()
        .flatMap(map -> map.keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    return budgetByMonth.values().stream()
        .filter(map -> map.keySet().stream().noneMatch(factByMonthKeys::contains))
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .map(entry -> entry.getValue().`~ get BigDecimal from Budget object somehow ~`)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I finally managed to solve the problem.